# Reset a column's MultiIndex levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a shorter way of dropping a column MultiIndex level (in my case, `basic_amt`) except transposing it twice?

```
In [704]: test
Out[704]: 
           basic_amt               
Faculty          NSW  QLD  VIC  All
All                1    1    2    4
Full Time          0    1    0    1
Part Time          1    0    2    3

In [705]: test.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
Out[705]: 
         basic_amt               
Faculty        NSW  QLD  VIC  All
0                1    1    2    4
1                0    1    0    1
2                1    0    2    3

In [711]: test.transpose().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).transpose()
Out[711]: 
Faculty    NSW  QLD  VIC  All
All          1    1    2    4
Full Time    0    1    0    1
Part Time    1    0    2    3
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Another solution is to use [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
import pandas as pd

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['basic_amt']*4,
                                     ['NSW','QLD','VIC','All']], 
                                     names = [None, 'Faculty'])
idx = pd.Index(['All', 'Full Time', 'Part Time'])

df = pd.DataFrame([(1,1,2,4),
                   (0,1,0,1),
                   (1,0,2,3)], index = idx, columns=cols)
                   
print (df)
          basic_amt            
Faculty         NSW QLD VIC All
All               1   1   2   4
Full Time         0   1   0   1
Part Time         1   0   2   3

df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
#pandas 0.18.0 and higher
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
#pandas bellow 0.18.0
#df.columns.name = None

print (df)
           NSW  QLD  VIC  All
All          1    1    2    4
Full Time    0    1    0    1
Part Time    1    0    2    3

print (df.columns)
Index(['NSW', 'QLD', 'VIC', 'All'], dtype='object')
```

If you need both column names, use `list` comprehension:

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df.columns]
print (df)
           basic_amt_NSW  basic_amt_QLD  basic_amt_VIC  basic_amt_All
All                    1              1              2              4
Full Time              0              1              0              1
Part Time              1              0              2              3

print (df.columns)
Index(['basic_amt_NSW', 'basic_amt_QLD', 'basic_amt_VIC', 'basic_amt_All'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Also to note:  If you have flattened a multi-index using '_' as a delimiter, and want to recreate it, you can do `my_tuples = [i.split("_") for i in df.columns]` and then `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(my_tuples)`

Answer (score 23):

## Zip levels together

Here is an alternative solution which zips the levels together and joins them with underscore.

Derived from the above answer, and this was what I wanted to do when I found this answer. Thought I would share even if it does not answer the exact above question.

```
["_".join(pair) for pair in df.columns]
```

gives

```
['basic_amt_NSW', 'basic_amt_QLD', 'basic_amt_VIC', 'basic_amt_All']
```

Just set this as a the columns

```
df.columns = ["_".join(pair) for pair in df.columns]

           basic_amt_NSW  basic_amt_QLD  basic_amt_VIC  basic_amt_All
Faculty                                                              
All                    1              1              2              4
Full Time              0              1              0              1
Part Time              1              0              2              3
```

Answer (score 20):

How about simply reassigning `df.columns`:

```
levels = df.columns.levels
labels = df.columns.labels
df.columns = levels[1][labels[1]]
```

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['basic_amt']*4,
                                     ['NSW','QLD','VIC','All']])
index = pd.Index(['All', 'Full Time', 'Part Time'], name = 'Faculty')
df = pd.DataFrame([(1,1,2,4),
                   (0,01,0,1),
                   (1,0,2,3)])
df.columns = columns
df.index = index
```

Before:

```
print(df)

           basic_amt               
                 NSW  QLD  VIC  All
Faculty                            
All                1    1    2    4
Full Time          0    1    0    1
Part Time          1    0    2    3
```

After:

```
levels = df.columns.levels
labels = df.columns.labels
df.columns = levels[1][labels[1]]
print(df)

           NSW  QLD  VIC  All
Faculty                      
All          1    1    2    4
Full Time    0    1    0    1
Part Time    1    0    2    3
```

Comment: That won't work if one has more than one category in MultiIndex level=0, and this (as per your example) also messes the order of columns. Can you think of a more general (and fail proof) solution?

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to work find for me. Can you give an example of the kind of DataFrame you are working with?

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(np.mat('0 1 0 1; 1 0 2 3; 1 1 2 4')))

Comment: arrays = [['a','a','b','b'],['one','two','one','two']] &&
tuples = zip(*arrays) &&
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['First','Second']) &&
df.columns = index
df.index = index[:3]

Comment: Indeed there was an error -- thanks for pointing it out. I think it is fixed now.

Comment: Not much shorter though. Both solutions would grant abstraction.

Comment: I agree it is not much shorter, but reassigning `df.columns` is about 4 times faster than `df.transpose().reset_index().transpose`.

Comment: Though this is an unfair comparison, because `df.transpose()...` returns a new DataFrame, while reassigning `df.columns` modifies the original DataFrame.

Comment: @unutbu I appreciate your solution very much, many thanx! One comment though - it is not generically "4 times faster", as this depends on the size of the DataFrame. In my case it 50,000 times faster! This may call for a feature request which is a `reset_index` analogue for columns...

Comment: I think it would be simpler to do df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(-1)
This make the last level of the columnar multi-index the only level.