# how do I change multindex to normal in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got this df after pivoting:

```
              grade value                               diff
              count             mean    
Period        20192     20202   20192       20202   
CourseRubric                    
course1        34.0     27.0    2.473529    3.700000    1.226471
course2        43.0     54.0    1.841860    2.990741    1.148880
course3        164.0    187.0   1.977439    3.042781    1.065342
```

How do I remove the multilevel indexing to this:

```
               grade value.count.20192    grade value.count.20202    grade value.mean.20192   grade value.mean.20202   diff
course1        34.0                       27.0                       2.473529                 3.700000                 1.226471
course2        43.0                       54.0                       1.841860                 2.990741                 1.148880
course3        164.0                      187.0                      1.977439                 3.042781                 1.065342
```

Or I would like to rename them in an easy way like gr_ct_19 etc but I do not know how to do that directly

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
df.columns = ['.'.join(map(str, col)) for col in df.columns]
```

See also:
[Reset a column's MultiIndex levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189695/reset-a-columns-multiindex-levels)

As pointed out by Ch3steR in the comments below: when a value in one of your column levels contains a numerical (or other non string), you need to convert that to a string first. That's why you need to apply `.map(str, col)` to your column name.

Comment: One problem is when `MultiIndex` has non str type in it e.g. `idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]])`

Comment: Edited so it works with mixed types to. Feel free to revert changes if not ok.

Comment: No problem.. ;)

Comment: The problem is I am getting brackets like this ('grade value', 'count', 20192) instead of gradevalue.count.20192 @Ch3steR

Comment: @JaySabir: can you show the (sample) code you are using currently, so we can see what causes this? This is what the columns look like before you apply the function i proposed, it's tuples.

Comment: @JaySabir Can you post the output of `print(df.columns)`

Comment: I removed the space in grade value and it is working now