# Pandas - Aggregate the data for all numeric columns in each year, and display the mean and sum of those columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a data frame that looks like the below. I'm trying to aggregate the data for all numeric columns in each year and display the mean and sum of those columns.

I interpret this to mean we want to combine the four columns besides Year and then find the sum and mean for that new column.

I'm struggling to do this.

```py
    Year    01-04 Years 05-09 Years 10-14 Years 15-19 Years
0   1900    0.019838    0.004661    0.002983    0.004848
1   1901    0.016950    0.004276    0.002736    0.004544
2   1902    0.016557    0.004033    0.002525    0.004215
3   1903    0.015421    0.004147    0.002682    0.004341
4   1904    0.015915    0.004250    0.003052    0.004714
... ... ... ... ... ...
114 2014    0.000240    0.000115    0.000140    0.000455
115 2015    0.000249    0.000117    0.000146    0.000483
116 2016    0.000253    0.000122    0.000146    0.000512
117 2017    0.000243    0.000116    0.000155    0.000515
118 2018    0.000240    0.000115    0.000149    0.000492
119 rows × 5 columns
```

I've come up with ...
mortality_wide.groupby('Year').agg(['mean', 'sum'])

But all that does is give the below which is not useful. How can I go about summing and finding the mean for each individual row grouped by Year?

```
01-04 Years 05-09 Years 10-14 Years 15-19 Years
mean    sum mean    sum mean    sum mean    sum
Year                                
1900    0.019838    0.019838    0.004661    0.004661    0.002983    0.002983    0.004848    0.004848
1901    0.016950    0.016950    0.004276    0.004276    0.002736    0.002736    0.004544    0.004544
1902    0.016557    0.016557    0.004033    0.004033    0.002525    0.002525    0.004215    0.004215
1903    0.015421    0.015421    0.004147    0.004147    0.002682    0.002682    0.004341    0.004341
1904    0.015915    0.015915    0.004250    0.004250    0.003052    0.003052    0.004714    0.004714
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2014    0.000240    0.000240    0.000115    0.000115    0.000140    0.000140    0.000455    0.000455
2015    0.000249    0.000249    0.000117    0.000117    0.000146    0.000146    0.000483    0.000483
2016    0.000253    0.000253    0.000122    0.000122    0.000146    0.000146    0.000512    0.000512
2017    0.000243    0.000243    0.000116    0.000116    0.000155    0.000155    0.000515    0.000515
2018    0.000240    0.000240    0.000115    0.000115    0.000149    0.000149    0.000492    0.000492
```

Comment: can you format your expected output?

Comment: Do you just want the mean/sum for each row?

Comment: Your data are essentially already grouped by year, so you can skip the `.groupby` and instead `.sum()` and `.mean()` along the "column" axis

Comment: I think OP is not satisfied with the format of the output of the .agg method. If that's the case, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37749078/6627366

Answer (score 2):

I am able to get the mean and sum for each year as

```py
df = df.set_index("Year")
print(df)

result_sum = df.sum(axis=1)
result_mean = df.mean(axis=1)

df["sum"] = result_sum
df["mean"] = result_mean

print(df)
```

this shows the result as

```
      01-04 Years  05-09 Years  10-14 Years  15-19 Years        sum      mean
Year
1900     0.019838     0.004661     0.002983     0.004848   0.032330  0.012932
1901     0.016950     0.004276     0.002736     0.004544   0.028506  0.011402
1902     0.016557     0.004033     0.002525     0.004215   0.027330  0.010932
1903     0.015421     0.004147     0.002682     0.004341   0.026591  0.010636
1904     0.015915     0.004250     0.003052     0.004714   0.027931  0.011172
```

we have to store sum and mean columns in a separate variable. otherwise, it will include sum column when calculating mean. that is why, i firstly assigned them to temporary variables and put them into main dataframe when calculations done.